# Windows CLI: pipe a list to awk and replace text with text from an external file and write output.txt

Tags: windows, dictionary, command-line, awk, pipe

I am a greenhorn with this stuff and have this problem, and i just can't figure it out:

A programm (e.G. listfilesonhdd) running in the windows commandline (cmd) that list files on hdd with a lot of infos and then pipes it to awk, because some text (with spaces) needs to be replaced with text (with spaces) in an external textfile, the file looks like this:

assoc.txt:

```
"this needs to be replaced" "with that"
"and that is replaced" "by that"
"and so on" "it goes"
"TO REPLACE" "WITH"
```

The text in the first column needs to be replaced with the text in the second one. awk has to replace matches in the "stream" that comes from the other program.

So i tried this commandline

```
listfilesonhdd | awk "FNR==NR {assoc[$1]=$2; next;} FNR<NR {for(key in assoc) {gsub(key, assoc[key])} printf}" assoc.txt > output.txt
```

and also

```
listfilesonhdd | awk "NR==FNR { a[$1]=$2; next} {for(i in a) {for(x=1;x<=NF;x++) {$x=(i==$x)?a[i]:$x}}}1" assoc.txt > output.txt
```

and other variations I found here, but it always gives me this error, sometimes the FNR number changes tho, no matter what I try and change:

```
awk: (FILENAME=- FNR=10) warning: error writing standard output (Invalid argument)
```

Probably it means, that the file is missing, where it has to replace the text, but I have no filename yet, I only have this piped data, so to say. Oh also tried it with gawk, same error.

I google for days and days, but I'm lost, I really would appreciate, if someone could help me find the error, please, thank you very much in advance (and sorry for my english).

Comment: `"this needs to be replaced"` is not a single field to awk. It is five fields: `"this`, `needs`, `to`, `be`, and `replaced`. So your awk script isn't doing what you want it to do. Also, at least here, awk doesn't read from both files and standard input like that (not without listing `-` as one of the filename arguments).

Answer (score 0):

`printf` requires arguments. You probably want `print` instead. you probably want to just remove the `FNR<NR` condition too as it's adding no value. Also, Windows quoting is a nightmare so put your awk script:

```
FNR==NR {assoc[$1]=$2; next}
{ for(key in assoc) gsub(key, assoc[key]); print }
```

in a file, say, `foo.awk` and execute it as

```
listfilesonhdd | awk -f foo.awk assoc.txt - > output.txt
```

to eliminate that issue.

I used `-` to represent stdin, if that's not the sytnax for that in WIndows, change it appropriately (I'm a UNIX guy).

You need to tell awk how to separate your input into fields by setting FS or FPAT or otherwise.

Note that `gsub(key,assoc[key])` in a loop can replace partial matches (e.g. you want to change `the` to `a` but find `there` converted to `are`) and can replaced text that already was replaced so it's a dubious approach. You might want to just loop in input fields instead and do `if ($i == key) $i = assoc[key]` or similar.

To demonstrate the issue of telling awk how to identify fields, look at the difference when this is run on your posted sample input file between the default setting of space-separated fields:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print NR, i, $i}' assoc.txt
1 1 "this
1 2 needs
1 3 to
1 4 be
1 5 replaced"
1 6 "with
1 7 that"
```

vs telling awk that fields are the strings between and including double quotes:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='"[^"]+"' 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print NR, i, $i}' assoc.txt
1 1 "this needs to be replaced"
1 2 "with that"
```

vs strings of non-double-quotes:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[^"]+' 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print NR, i, $i}' assoc.txt
1 1 this needs to be replaced
1 2
1 3 with that
```

Those last ones use FPAT which is a GNU awk extension. Other awks have different solutions but that's the simplest.

Comment: Hi @Ed, thank you for your answer.It is of course print instead of printf, I copied it wrong. I removed the FNR<NR part. But the first line is working now, it was only the missing - to represent stdin, that caused the error. But it changes only WORD1 with WORD2, so how can i tell awk to use the "complete text"?  Ops, sorry,... there are , to separate the fields yes, can i use FS="\"" or FS="," or something?

Comment: As @EtanReiser and I both mentioned, you need to tell awk how to separate your input into fields. By default fields are space-separated so every separate word is a field. It looks like you want to replace whole sentences so - how can awk tell when one sentence ends and the other begins? Are there tab chars between sentences and none within sentences or is it something else? Do the same rules apply to both input streams? Post an example of the output from the `listfilesonhold` command piping into awk, and the desired output.

Comment: I updated my answer to demonstrate the issue of telling awk how to identify fields.